# REGEX JAVA Localizar um trecho em todo o documento

Tags: java, regex

Estou tentando desenvolver uma expressão Regex na linguagem JAVA para que encontre e valide a existência de uma pequena sequencia de caracteres dentro de um .txt.

Exp:

Validar a existência da sequência `TDT+20+LA8031+++LA'` dentro do texto abaixo:

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+UNOA:4+TAM:JJ+APIAR:ZZ+170911:1456+1709111456++APIS'
UNG+PAXLST+TAM:JJ+APIAR:ZZ+170911:1456+1709111456+UN+D:02B'
UNH+CRW001+PAXLST:D:02B:UN:IATA'
BGM+250+DC:1.0'
TDT+20+LA8031+++LA'
LOC+125+GRU'
DTM+189:1709091315:201'
LOC+87+AEP'
DTM+232:1709091610:201'
NAD+FM+++RAVAZZOLLI ABUD SILVA:MARCELO+454 AGOSTINHO DE FARIA+SAO PAULO+SP+0828
0 100+BRA'
ATT+2++M'
DTM+329:680426'
NAT+2+BRA'
DOC+P:110:109+F0722522'
DTM+36:251102'
LOC+91+BRA'
NAD+FM+++BOCK PEREIRA:RICARDO+209 NHU GUACU AP 104+SAO PAULO+SP+04625001+BRA'
ATT+2++M'
DTM+329:800513'
NAT+2+BRA'
DOC+P:110:109+FR676533'
DTM+36:261003'
LOC+91+BRA'
NAD+FM+++BARBOSA DA SILVA:THIAGO+RUA PELOTAS  323 AP 143+SAO PAULO+SP+04012 903
+BRA'
```

O problema é que o texto não tem muito padrões, podem vir mais ou menos linhas antes do trecho pesquisado e tal. Teria alguma forma simples de o regex varrer todo o texto e validar apenas esse pequeno trecho?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pesquisar uma sequência de símbolos em determinada ordem usa-se (...), por exemplo (xyz) para x seguido de y e z. No seu caso tem alguns símbolos reservados então usamos a \ para usa-los como literais.

A resposta é `(TDT\+20\+LA8031\+\+\+LA)`, veja funcionando no https://regex101.com/r/HoqPUk/2